# python virtual environment with different python version than system python and installing packages

Tags: python3, virtualenv

I created a python 3.9.7 virtual environment using virtualenv.  This is a different python version than my system python.  When I try install jupyter via `pip install jupyter` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/Python-3.9.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/bin/Python-3.9.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import CommandError
  File "/home/kmdreve/jupyter_notebook/kmdreve3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/Python-3.9.7` folder for local python is bad idea. Use `/usr/local` or `/opt` for such things. Instead use https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv .

Comment: can you explain maybe a little more why it is a bad idea?

Comment: 1. This folder is maintained by APT, 2. you break FHS by creating directories here.

Comment: ah thank you! Good to know!